# Converting from java to C++

Tags: java

How do I convert the following to C++

```
public class Palindrome
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String phrase;
        Palindrome program = new Palindrome();

        /*gets a phrase from the user and reads it*/
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Enter a phrase =>");
        System.out.flush();

        phrase = keyboard.readLine();

        /*determines if the phrase is a palindrome and prints result*/
        if(!program.isPalindrome(phrase))
            System.out.println("The phrase is NOT a palindrome.");

        else System.out.println("The phrase is a palindrome.");

    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String testString)
    {
        Stack s = new Stack();
        Queue q = new Queue();
        String temp = testString.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        Character c = new Character(temp.charAt(i));
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(c.charValue())) {
            s.push(c);
            q.enqueue(c);
        }
        }
        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        Character a = (Character)s.pop();
        Character b = (Character)q.dequeue();
        if (!a.equals(b))
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Queue
{
        private LinkedList myList;

    public Queue()
    {
        myList = new LinkedList();
    }

    /**
     * This method should return null if the Queue is empty
     */
    public Object deQueue()
    {
        return myList.removeHead();
    }

    public void enQueue(Object addObj)
    {
        myList.addTail(addObj);
    }

    /**
     * This method should return true if the queue has no more 
     * elements in it
     */
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        myList.resetIndex();
        return (myList.getIndexedNode() == null);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Stack
{
        private LinkedList myList;

    public Stack()
    {
        myList = new LinkedList();
    }

    /**
     * This method should return null if the Stack is empty
     */
    public Object pop()
    {
        return myList.removeHead();
    }

    public void push(Object addObj)
    {
        myList.addHead(addObj);
    }

    /**
     * This method should return true if the stack has no more 
     * elements in it
     */
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        myList.resetIndex();
        return (myList.getIndexedNode() == null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Get a book on C. Edit: Honestly, though, there's a lot of Java code here such that most people won't touch it. Your best bet is to maybe find software that can do it, or learn enough C to do it yourself.

Comment: You write the C++ equivalent to the listed Java code.

Comment: SO is not a "write me code for free" service.  If you have a specific programming question, please ask it.

Comment: This seems like homework

Comment: Voting to close. You should have tried something than posting the dump here and asking for how to convert.

Comment: and why do you have your own stack and queue classes. Those are in the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that this is a valid question, I think I'd do it something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool is_palindrome(std::string const &input) { 
    return input == std::string(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
}

int main() { 
    std::cout << "Enter a phrase =>";
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    std::cout << 
        (is_palindrome(input) 
            ? "Phrase is a palindrome" 
            : "Phrase is not a palindrome");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why you'd use a stack or a deque for this, but if you did, it seems like the ones in the standard library would do the job perfectly well.